# MongoDb - What is bestpractise for querying on subcollection with Entityframework Core

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Consider that, there is an AggregateRoot that named `A` and it has a collection that named `B`

```
public class A
{
   ... properties
   public ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
   ... lots of properties
}
```

I want to make an endpoint on my web application for `B`. So I need to querying on `B`, filtering, showing etc. them individually. I've got some troubles to do it. What is the best way to make it?

**Tried way**

Get all `A` that has any `B` for your query, then select `B`s.

problems:

1. `A` can have some `B`s that is not satisfied by my filter, so I need to filter those again in memory.
2. The problem 2 occurs one more problem, If I want to pagination for my filtered `B`s, the pagination will not stabile.

Comment: You can query `B` directly and show their `A` parent's properties as well.

Comment: @GertArnold, I do it as you said. But for when I want to make a pagination, the pagination does not work correctly, or I could not make it well.
For example, my query returns 5 ```A``` and consider iti those have 5 different ```B```s. Totally 25 B I have, then I refiltered and I get 20 what I really want. If I implement pagination 10 by 10, how I show to user the second page's ```B```s'?

Comment: No, your query should return `B`s. Only then it's possible to page `B`s properly.